# Save values and use it thrught all subsequent redirect in Fiddler

Tags: http, fiddler, jscript.net

I want to save a value in a variable and use it in following requests.
How can I save data in a persistent way?

Comment: I would assume this is possible writing custom FidderScript. There you can save data to a variable or to a file. https://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-fiddlerscript

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem saving my data in a file and than I read it in the next request:

```
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),
    thefile=fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\temp\\bogusToken.txt",true);
    thefile.Write(token);
    thefile.Close();
    ...
    my_Token = File.ReadAllText("C:\\temp\\bogusToken.txt");
```